# Fourier transform of a class of interesting functions to optimize a numerical algorithm

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

I try to speed up a numerical algorithm and I came to a class of real functions where I need the Fourier transform or the coefficients of the Fourier series with a large interval of them.

The class of functions is

$$f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R, \qquad f(x) = \frac{a|x-b|}{1+a(x-b)^{2}}$$

with $a>0$ and $b \in \mathbb R$

Every help is welcome (solutions, formulas, links)
and of course also the counter proof if it is not analytical solvable. The actual goal would be to get the Fourier coefficients of

$$f(x) = \frac{a\|x-b\|}{1+a\|x-b\|^{2}}$$

with $a>0$ and $x,b\in \Bbb R^{3}$, but I would be also very thankful for help with the $1$-dimensional case.

Comment: You can reduce to the case $a=1,b=0$ in any dimension by standard properties of the Fourier transform. But Wolfram cannot find an explicit solution https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=fourier+transform+of+abs%28x%29%2F%281%2Bx%5E2%29

Comment: I would index $f$, i.e., use $f_{a,b}$. A related question would be to find the values of $(a,b)$ for which $f_{a,b}$ has a Fourier transform.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo they are $\widehat{f_{a,b}} (\xi)= \frac{e^{ib\xi}}a \widehat{f_{1,0}} (\xi/a)$, (or something like this, perhaps missing a minus sign or $2\pi$). They all have Fourier transforms (they are all in $L^2(\mathbb R)$, or at least locally integrable for dimension 3), but I'm not sure an explicit form ("analytical solution") can be found (and an explicit formula for any gives a formula for all)

Comment: **Maple 2022** says:$$2 \cosh \! \left(\frac{w}{\sqrt{a}}\right) \left(\sin \! \left(w b \right) \mathrm{I}-\cos \! \left(w b \right)\right) \mathrm{Ci}\! \left(\frac{w \mathrm{I}}{\sqrt{a}}\right)+\pi  \left(\cos \! \left(w b \right) \mathrm{I}+\sin \! \left(w b \right)\right) \mathrm{signum}\! \left(w \right) \cosh \! \left(\frac{w}{\sqrt{a}}\right)-2 \sinh \! \left(\frac{w}{\sqrt{a}}\right) \left(\sin \! \left(w b \right) \mathrm{I}-\cos \! \left(w b \right)\right) \mathrm{Shi}\! \left(\frac{w}{\sqrt{a}}\right)
$$ where **Ci** is cosine integral and **Shi** is hyperbolic sine integral.

Answer (score 1):

Following the comment of [@calvin-khor](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/80734/calvin-khor) this is for $a=1$, $b=0$.  It may also show how the special functions found by [@mariusz-iwaniuk](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/276773/mariusz-iwaniuk) arise, though I will do it in terms of exponential integrals.

The Fourier transform can be written
$$
\hat f(\omega) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{|x|e^{-i\omega x}}{1+x^2} d\omega = 2\Re\left\{\int_0^\infty \frac{ze^{-i\omega z}}{1+z^2} dz\right\}
$$
Taking $\omega > 0$, the path of integration can be rotated onto the positive imaginary axis.  There is a pole at $z=i$, which leads to a Cauchy principal value integral and half a residue:
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty \frac{ze^{-i\omega z}}{1+z^2} dz &= \int_0^\infty -\frac{ye^{-\omega y}}{1-y^2} dy + i\pi Res_{z=i}\frac{ze^{-i\omega z}}{1+z^2} \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\left[\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-\omega y}}{y-1}dy + \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-\omega y}}{y+1} dy + i\pi e^{-\omega}\right] \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\left[e^{-\omega}\int_{-1}^\infty\frac{e^{-\omega t}}{t}dt + e^{\omega}\int_1^\infty \frac{e^{-\omega t}}{t} dy + i\pi e^{-\omega}\right]
\end{align}
Each of the integrals can be expressed in terms of the Exponential integral https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral. One might want to take care of how the first (PV) integral can be written in terms of $E_1$, but the difference is purely imaginary so doesn't matter when taking the real part (nor does the residue term at the end).  Thus we find
$$
\hat f(\omega) = \Re\{e^\omega E_1(\omega) + e^{-\omega} E_1(-\omega)\}
$$
which is also valid for $\omega < 0$.